# How to create a table?

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset

I have looked here at the forum and on the mathematica documentation center though still couldn't get it to work.

I have two lists

```
data1 = Range[5,100,5];
data2 = {23.5371, 19.9289, 17.3337, 15.2521, 13.5116, 12.0224, 10.728, 
9.58869, 8.57414, 7.66085, 6.83212, 6.0777, 5.39243, 4.77407, 
4.22107, 3.73117, 3.30078, 2.92517, 2.59882, 2.31598};
data3 = {0.825641, 0.744071, 0.671229, 0.606114, 0.54784, 0.49552, 0.448347, 
0.405579, 0.366531, 0.33061, 0.297385, 0.266627, 0.238275, 0.212363, 
0.188934, 0.167979, 0.149416, 0.133096, 0.118823, 0.106381};
```

How can I get a table from this data form such as this:
[image]

I have tried to use Grid and tried to use TableForm but I couldn't arrange the data in a way visualized above.

Comment: The answer to this question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59677/creating-a-table-giving-the-statistics-of-random-polynomials tells you all.

Answer (score 13):

```
Grid[Transpose@{data1, data2, data3} ~Prepend~ {"data1", "data2", "data3"}, 
  Dividers -> {All, {1 -> True, 2 -> True, -1 -> True}}]
```

> [image: Grid]

Comment: A bit more compact: `Dividers -> {All, {True, True, {}, True}}`

Answer (score 7):

If you often have need of this display you will want a function to automate creating the code in Karsten's answer (with a few variations):

```
SetAttributes[mytable, HoldFirst]

mytable[dat : {__}?MatrixQ, opts : OptionsPattern[Grid]] :=
  Grid[
    Join[{Thread @ HoldForm @ dat}, dat\[Transpose]],
    opts, Dividers -> {All, {1, 1, {}, 1}}
  ]
```

Example, including an additional `Grid` Option:

```
mytable[{data1, data2, data3}, Alignment -> "."]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Grid[{{"data1", "data2", "data3"}, Column /@ {data1, data2, data3}}, 
 Frame -> All]
```

Comment: The disadvantage of this is that you lose alignment between columns and other `Grid` niceties.